# Prolog read keys and print values corresponding to the key

Tags: prolog, repeat

I have to implement a Prolog program, that accepts a List like [[1,a],[2,b],[1,c]] and asks for a Key in a loop. If the user enters 1 [a,c] should be printed and the user should be asked for the next key until the user enters 'exit'.

My current program:

```
%Input: AssocList and Key.
%Output: FindList which contains all Values associated with the Key in AssocList.
as_find(AssocList, Key, FindList) :- 
    as_find(AssocList, Key, Acc, FindList).

as_find([], Key, Acc, Acc).
as_find([], Key, Acc, FindList) :- as_find([], Key, Acc, Acc).
as_find([[Key,D]|R], Key, Acc, FindList) :- my_append(D, Acc, NewFindList), as_find(R, Key, NewFindList, FindList).
as_find([[H,D]|R], Key, List, FindList) :- as_find(R, Key, List, FindList).

%Appends Elem to the given list and returns it in the other list.
my_append(Elem,[],[Elem]).
my_append(Elem,[H|R],[H|Z]) :- my_append(Elem,R,Z).  

%Asks for Keys and writes all Values associated with the keys.
as_search(List) :-
  repeat,
  write('Key?'),
  read(Key),   
  as_find(List, Key, FindList),
  write(FindList),
  Key == 'genug',
  !.
```

Unfortunately If I use another Key than 'done' the programm will end in an infinite loop. Can you please help?

Regards,
hyperion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program uses a failure driven loop, you start the program with the goal. `?-start.` you are then prompted to add the list. You can change this if you want the list hardcoded into the program and not as user input. We then enter the loop, we give a term for example `1.` the system will then print matching values from the list and loop. If you enter `stop.`the program terminates.

```
start:-
   format("Enter list:\n",[]),
   read(List),
   enter(List).

enter(List):-
  format("Enter key or stop:\n",[]),
  read(X),
  test(X,List).

test(stop,_):-!.
test(X,List):-
  findall(Y,member([X,Y],List), Values),
  format("~w\n",[Values]),
  enter(List).
```

If you enter a key that does not exist in the list, an empty list will print and take you back to try again.

Example run:

```
 ?- start.
 Enter list:
 |: [[1,a],[2,b],[1,c]].
 Enter key or stop:
 |: 1.
 [a,c]
 Enter key or stop:
 |: 2.
 [b]
 Enter key or stop:
 |: stop.

false.
```

A different version using repeat:

```
start:-
  format("Enter list:\n",[]),
  read(List),
  format("Enter key or stop:\n",[]),
  repeat,
  read(X),
  (   X=stop->!;
    (     findall(Y,member([X,Y],List), Values),
          format("~w\n",[Values]),
          format("Enter key or stop:\n",[])),
          fail).
```

Comment: Is there any benefit in using `fail` in the clause bodies of `test/2`?

Comment: I guess you don't need the second fail. The first fail depends on if you want the goal to succeed or fail by default. Ill edit it to remove them.

Comment: Right! There may be no single best way. But keeping things simple is a good default, IMO.

Comment: Hi, your program works well, but actually I have to use repeat as this is the  purpose of the excercise.

Comment: @hyperion Added another version using repeat.